# Finding subsets of size k from a larger set using decrease-and-conquer

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

**Disclosure: This is homework. I'm attempting to provide all of the information required to meet SO's rules; I apologize if I miss something.**

I'm using Python, and I need to generate all subsets of length k from a list of n integers (non-repeating permutations). The program needs to be a decrease-and-conquer program. I think I'm on the right track with the code I've provided below, but I just can't make the connection between it and the final solution. *I'm not asking for a solution, just for some help that will point me in the right direction.*

I'm fairly sure I could easily do this iteratively *(this is incorrect as shown in the comments)*:

- Initialize two loops with `i = 0` and `j = k-1`

  - Print the three elements from `A[i]` to `A[i+k-1]`
  - Print `A[j]`
  - Increment `j` until the end of the list is reached
- Increment `i`, repeat until `i == n - k - 1`

I'm not really sure how to translate this over to a decrease-and-conquer function, however. I know I'll need to use recursion of some sort, of course, but I don't know *how* to use recursion for this function. I know it's completely wrong, but this is the code I've written thus far.

```
def permutations(A, k):
    if len(A) < k:
        print "Step:"
        print A
        return A
    else:
        new = []
        new = permutations(A[:-2], k)       
        new.append(A[-1])
        return new

if __name__ == '__main__':
    useList = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
    useK = 3
    final = permutations(useList, useK)
    print "Final list:"
    print final
```

This code produces the following output ("Step" is there for debugging):

```
Step:
[10, 20]
Final list:
[10, 20, 40, 60, 80]
```

Ignoring "Step" for debugging, the output should be similar to this (though the exact method/order of displaying the final results does not matter):

```
[10, 20, 30]
[10, 20, 40]
[10, 20, 50]
...
```

...with one entry for each subset of 3 integers. Once [10, 20, 80] is reached, we'd move on to [20, 30, 40], etc.

Comment: Permutations are of two types, repeating and non repeating. Which one are you trying to implement?

Comment: Ah, good point, thank you. Non-repeating. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: So what **does** that code do? What output do you get, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Can you add an example? Using the set {10, 20, 30, 40} and k=2, what should the function output?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I've updated the original post with that information now.

Comment: For inspiration take a look at the implementation of the combinations function in itertools. https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: I don't understand your iterative algorithm, which makes it hard to explain how to convert it to recursive. Why would you print the four elements `A[i]`, `A[i+1]`, `A[i+2]`, and `A[j]`? For example, how are you ever going elements 0, 2, 3, and 4 this way?

Comment: That being said, if you know how to write it recursively, you can convert to recursion semi-mechanically. See [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/w56K4GPE) for a simple example, but you'll do better to find a tutorial on looping recursively. At any rate, your iterative algorithm doesn't seem to be divide-and-conquer (it's just knocking off one element at a time, not splitting it in half), so I don't think that's what you're supposed to be doing, but it's at least worth making sure you know how to do that…

Comment: Think about some particular element, say the first element A[0] in the list, in relation to the set of all k-subsets.  Every subset of k elements either contains A[0], or it doesn't.  So already we have the beginnings of a strategy: if we could generate all k-subsets that contain A[0], and then generate all k-subsets that don't contain A[0], we will have generated all k-subsets, which is our goal.  Next question: Do these two kinds of k-subset overlap?  I.e. is it possible that we could generate some k-subset twice with this approach?

Comment: ... The answer to that last question should be obvious.  So then, how to actually generate these 2 kinds of k-subset?  I'll give you a clue for the k-subsets that don't contain A[0]: A k-subset of {A[0], ..., A[n-1]} that doesn't contain A[0] is the same as a ___-subset of {A[1], ..., A[n-1]}, so if we could generate all of the latter then we can generate all of the former.  "If only we had a function that would generate them all..." ;-)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: That all makes total sense. I can pass A[1..n-1] back to the function recursively (leaving A[0] out), but I don't know how to handle it from there. I don't know what the base case should be; I just don't know how to handle it recursively. I tried using len(A) == k and k+1 when I was messing with it a couple hours ago, and I thought I had made some progress, but I was WAY off. It's not explicitly stated that we can't use Python functions (like itertools.combinations), but I think I'll be marked down if I do (if that's what you were getting at).

Comment: I guess I still just don't see the overall picture.

Comment: So you know how to generate one of the two kinds of k-subset, good.  For the other kind: a k-subset of {A[0], ..., A[n-1]} that *does* contain A[0] is the same as a ___-subset of {A[1], ..., A[n-1]}, plus ___.  Hint for the base case: How many size-42 subsets are there of a 42-element set?

Comment: Actually I've just looked at your code now.  What must the return type (in English, I know Python doesn't have static types) of `permutations()` be, to get the result you want?  Once you figure that out, you should be able to see that `new.append(A[-1])` assumes the wrong "type" for `new`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up asking my professor for further help. The method used involves generating a list of binary strings, where 1 is an "activated" index and 0 is an "inactivated" index. Once the binary strings are generated, it's a simple matter to use them to generate the list of subsets.

The final (commented) code is below. I'll leave the output out so as to save space; the program can be run easily enough.

```
#create list of binary strings representing indices of all subsets of k elements from a
#list n elements long
def permutations(n, k):
    #base case 1: handles the recursion where n-1 and k are being passed to the function
    #return n 1's in a string: '1...1'
    if n == k:
        s = str()        #initialize s as an empty list
        m = 0
        while m < n:     #loop from 0 (empty list) to n elements in the list
            s += '1'     #append the number 1 as an element to the list
            m += 1
        return [s]       #return the list back from the recursion

    #base case 2: handles the recursion where n-1 and k-1 are being passed to the function
    #return n 0's in a string: '0...0'; empty string if n == 0
    elif k == 0:
        s = str()        #initialize s as an empty list
        m = 0
        while m < n:     #loop from 0 (empty list) to n elements in the list
            s += '0'     #append the number 0 as an element to the list
            m += 1
        return [s]       #return the list back from the recursion
    else:
        listN_1 = permutations(n - 1, k)
        listK_1 = permutations(n - 1, k - 1)

        listN = []
        for item in listN_1:
            listN.append(str(item) + '0')
        for item in listK_1:
            listN.append(str(item) + '1')
        return listN

#return subsets from a given list using a list of binary strings
def convertPerms(bStrings, useList):
    final = []              #initialize empty list to be returned by function
    for item in bStrings:   #loop through each list element (each binary string)
        l = []              #initialize list for THIS binary string iteration
        item = list(item)
        for (i, s) in enumerate(item):   #iterate through binary string, including keys
            if int(s) == 1:                   #if value == 1...
                l.append(useList[i])     #...append useList item at this index to THIS string's list

        final.append(l)   #append THIS string's list to final list
    return final   #return final list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    useList = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
    useK = 3
    perms = permutations(len(useList), useK)
    final = convertPerms(perms, useList)
    print "Final list:"
    for item in final:
        print item
```